# How to Instatiate a Child with Parent Construct

Tags: php

So I am attempting to learn object oriented php and have a bit of a hang up on inheriting parent constructs in child classes. In the example below, if I wanted to instantiate the `CdProduct` class (say john smith has an audiobook as well). How would I, instantiate the `CdProduct` class and set the `playLength` but use the `$title`, `$firstName`, and `$mainName` from the construct of the parent class?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```php
class ShopProduct
{
    public $title;
    public $firstName;
    public $mainName;
    public $price;

    function __construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerMainName = $mainName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}

class CdProduct extends ShopProduct
{
    public $playLength;

    function __construct($title, $firstName,$mainName, $price, $playLength)
    {
        parent::__construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price);
        $this->playLength = $playLength;
    }
}

$shopP1 = new ShopProduct("book","john","smith", "0.01");
$CDprod1 = new CdProduct /* WHAT WOULD I NEED TO DO HERE */
```

Comment: /* WHAT WOULD I NEED TO DO HERE */ => well, you need to specify the arguments expected by the class constructor: `function __construct( $title, $firstName,$mainName, $price, $playLength )`. The next line then hands over some arguments to the parents class constructor: `parent::__construct( $title, $firstName, $mainName, $price );`. So all looks fine to me.

Comment: Oh, and BTW: the code of the parent classes constructor will execute, but that is certainly not what you want: there is not class property `producerFirstName` or `producerMainName`. Only `firstName` and `mainName` is defined in that class.

Comment: That's right. I went over this maybe a week or two ago. It's coming back to me now. Thanks.